# Single domain with multiple servers

Tags: networking, dns

Let's say I have 10 servers spread around the world and one of it is in the U.S; having 1 domain name for all the servers with different ip address.

And in this case, a user is trying to access from the U.S.
Is the DNS that is the one who organise and figure out the nearest server to use for that user or it's the server side that's doing the job?

In the domain hosting, there is DNS zones. How is this related to? As i see that all the ip address are there under one domain name.

What does this process call so I can find out and read and learn more about this?

Thank you in advance for helping me out in this.

Comment: Check out anycast in the context of DNS.

Comment: There are ways to do this depending on what kind of servers you are using and there are also a few services that will do this for you. i really don't have enough info to give you a best option. For instance this function is built into apache